# AppleScript Run Application

Tags: macos, applescript

I have this script here that needs to mount a network folder, verify that it is mounted, and then start the application. When 'tell application appName to activate' is outside the 'tell application "System Events"' statement, it works. But as it is written below, the application will not open.  Additionally, when I replace 'appName' with "QuickBooks", the programs opens as it is written below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
set hostname to "TestHost"
set shareFolder to "TestShare"
set user to "TestUser"
set pw to "P@ssword"
set appName to "QuickBooks"

try
    set networkPath to "/volumes/" & shareFolder
    mount volume "smb://" & hostname & "/" & shareFolder as user name user with password pw
end try

tell application "System Events"
    if exists folder networkPath then
        tell application appName to activate
    else
        display alert "Unable to find QuickBooks Database."
    end if
    
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
tell application appName to activate
```

to

```
tell me to tell application appName to activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt's answer really worked. I couldn't get an AppleScript Application to launch another app at all in Monterey. Was using standard "tell application ...". I'm nearly positive that used to work on older Mac OS. Anyway. This worked great and now I have it in Login Items. Thanks again Matt.

For anyone interested, this was the code. Export, FF: Application, Run-only, Sign to run Locally.

```
delay 10
tell application "System Events"
    tell me to tell application "BetterTouchTool" to activate
end tell
```